# MySQL Query Questions with a Foreign Key Database

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb

Here's some background info. I have three MySQL tables (all InnoDB). The first table is used to store images records. The second table is used to store tags (to **tag** the images with. OMG). The third table is used to store relationships between the images and the tags. Yippee. Here's the structure of the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `images_to_tags` (
  `image_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `images_to_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `images_to_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `images` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The *type* field in the images database is either "image/gif", "image/png", or "image/jpeg".

And there you have it. So my tables are happily populated with a quarter million images, 10,000 tags, and a metric shit load of image-tag relationships.

1) I need to be able to count how many images have tags. Currently I am doing so with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT image_id) 
  FROM images_to_tags
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this? It seems kind of circuitous. Is this the only reasonable query which will achieve this purpose?

2) For each *type* of image, I want to find out **how many images are tagged**. So say about 5,000 total images have tags, how would I know how many of those 5,000 tagged images are of *type* "image/png".  This isn't working for me:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), type 
  FROM images, 
       images_to_tags 
 WHERE images.id = images_to_tags.image_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on your first query would be:

```
select count(*) 
from images_to_tags
group by image_id
```

For your second:

```
select type, count(*) 
from images 
where id in (select image_id from images_to_tags)
group by type
```

Comment: @mecablaze: I modified my second query after reading your comment to Aaron W.

Comment: The first query returns a list of how many occurrences of each tag_id there is.

The second query does the same as the other comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442576/mysql-query-questions-with-a-foreign-key-database/1442619#1442619)

Comment: Ah my bad. The second one works perfectly. I will definitely look into the 'in' syntax.

Comment: Correct, first one is wrong, it's late :) Nothing wrong with your first query - if speed is a problem make sure image_id is indexed (not sure if making it part of a primary key will cause it to be indexed in MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the count of how many images that have tags properly.  If you want a count of tags for each image type you should do a count and group by the type.  Try this

```
SELECT count(`id`), `type` FROM `images`, `images_to_tags` WHERE `images`.`id` = `images_to_tags`.`image_id` GROUP BY `images`.`type`
```

Comment: This counts the total number of tags each images say, organized by type. I was looking for the total number of images that are tagged, organized by type. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Try making the count similar to your first query

SELECT count(DISTINCT `images_to_tags`.`image_id`), `type` FROM `images`, `images_to_tags` WHERE `images`.`id` = `images_to_tags`.`image_id` GROUP BY `images`.`type`